# not in search query in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I was wondering if there is a search query using the elasticsearch DSL for finding all the values except some that satisfy a certain condition on a dateOptionalTime field in the database.

The equivalent `SQL query` would be:

```
select * from index 
where (not (date="0001-01-01T00:00:00+03:30")) 
and (domain="somthing.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `bool/must_not` to achieve this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "domain": "something.com"
        }
      },
      "must_not": {
        "term": {
          "date": "0001-01-01T00:00:00+03:30"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```